# Perl script Can't locate Text/Template.pm in @INC

Tags: mysql, perl

I am trying to tune the MySQL tuner script written in Perl. But getting the error below:

```
root@server2 [/tmp]# perl mysqltuner.pl
Can't locate Text/Template.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at mysqltuner.pl line 2816.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at mysqltuner.pl line 2816 (#1)
    (F) You said to do (or require, or use) a file that couldn't be
    found. Perl looks for the file in all the locations mentioned in @INC,
    unless the file name included the full path to the file.  Perhaps you
    need to set the PERL5LIB or PERL5OPT environment variable to say where
    the extra library is, or maybe the script needs to add the library name
    to @INC.  Or maybe you just misspelled the name of the file.  See
    perlfunc/require and lib.

Uncaught exception from user code:
        Can't locate Text/Template.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at mysqltuner.pl line 2816.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at mysqltuner.pl line 2816.
 at mysqltuner.pl line 2816
```

It would glad to provide solution for the  same.

Comment: Your script is trying to import a module `Text::Template`, but cannot find it. That's not a core module, so you may need to install it.

Comment: i have alrady installed  the text::Template module /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Template.pm
/usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Exception/Template.pm
/usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Exim/Config/Template.pm
/usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/ZoneFile/Template.pm
/usr/local/cpanel/Whostmgr/Template.pm
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/HTML/Template.pm
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Net/OSCAR/XML/Template.pm
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux/Template.pm
/usr/local/lib64/perl5/Template.pm
/usr/local/share/perl5/Net/OSCAR/XML/Template.pm
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/HTML/Template.pm

Comment: @rishidadwal I don't see `Text/Template.pm` in there. *How* did you install it?

Answer (score 2):

In your perl script `mysqltuner.pl`, you are using a module [Text::Template](http://search.cpan.org/~mjd/Text-Template-1.46/lib/Text/Template.pm) which is not installed in your system, that's why you are getting this warning.
You can installed it by using cpan. If you are on Linux system, open a terminal and type:

```
sudo cpan install Text::Template #sudo is not required if you have login as root.
```

If you are on windows system and using ActivePerl, use this:

```
ppm install Text-Template
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply   /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Template.pm
/usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Exception/Template.pm
/usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Exim/Config/Template.pm
/usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/ZoneFile/Template.pm
/usr/local/cpanel/Whostmgr/Template.pm
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/HTML/Template.pm
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Net/OSCAR/XML/Template.pm
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux/Template.pm
/usr/local/lib64/perl5/Template.pm
/usr/local/share/perl5/Net/OSCAR/XML/Template.pm
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/HTML/Template.pm

Answer (score 0):

Open Command Promt. Type in the following:

`ppm install Text-Template`

Comment: ppm is the package manager for ActivePerl on Windows. The OP seems to work on a linux system.